# Move Back to swrevealviewcontrtoller menu Action not working

Tags: swift, swrevealviewcontroller

In my app, I use a SWRevealViewController for the side menu, and I have it set up correctly. My problem is that from a view controller that has a side menu, I have a segue to go to another view controllers that doesn't use SWRevealViewController. Then on action go back to the SWRevealViewController. (a details Viewcontroller). For some reason the menu button stops displaying the menu.

Comment: please provide code .......

Comment: @IBAction func homeButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchsegue", sender: self)
    }

Comment: please provide your some code exactly what are you trying to do?